# What is the differnce between Service Worker and GCM

Tags: javascript

I am really confused about the two technologies GCM and Service worker. We can use both for push notifications but the service worker are specifically for browser push notifications and GCM for mobiles. This is my theory about the above mentioned technologies. If i wrong then please share your valuable suggestions and give me a right guide.

Comment: These are completely different things. GCM is for push notifications, and a service worker is for running background tasks

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about [GCM, the Galois/Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) for symmetric key cryptographic ciphers? No? Perhaps a bit of searching would help clear things up...

Answer (score 1):

> Service Worker

A service worker is basically a special javascript environment, that runs in the background of browsers. Websites can register service workers and then they can run some code in the background.

> GCM

Is a product of Google, which basically provides a server API for sending messages across devices. If you combine them with a service worker, you can send notifications to Chrome whenever you want (if the user allows you to register a worker).

Comment: So could we send push notifications without GCM and could we send it using Service worker

Comment: @LuqMaN yes you can send notifications to every server you want. However you can only receive notifications via GCM as Chrome is maintained by Google.